# swig -c++ option breaks wrapper of pure C files with error C3861:unresolved externals

Tags: python, c++, c, swig

I am trying to wrap a C API I was given so it can be use in Python using SWIG. This API requires call back functions be passed to it from Python (Python passing a Python function to C which is called from C and executed in Python). This is doable using C++ and directors - `%module(directors="1")`. However when I add the `-c++` option to the swig set-up file it fails to find any of the C functions in the linking stage. It compiles fine and will run in Python, less the needed callbacks, before I add the `-c++` option.

I have created a very simple example of this form the demo code:

add.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int add_func(int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
}
```

add.h:

```
int add_func(int x, int y);
```

add.i:

```
%module add
%{
    #include "add.h"
%}
%include "add.h"
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
    name='add',
    py_modules=['add'],
    ext_modules=[
        Extension('_add',
                  sources=['add.c', 'add.i'],
                  swig_opts=['-c++']
        )
    ]
)
```

compile command:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

with `swig_ops=['-c++']` I get the following error:

```
add_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl add_func(int,int)" (?add_func@@YAHHH@Z)
build\lib.win32-3.8\_add.cp38-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

with `swig_ops=['-c++']` removed it compiles fine.

So the question is can you use pure C code with C++ and swig? If so how?

System info:

> ```
> SWIG Version 4.0.2
> Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 > 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 exe
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The generated wrapper is C++ but `add.c` is compiled as C and has C linkage.  The error message indicates it is looking for `add_func` with C++ linkage.

Either add `extern "C"` to the `add.h` prototype so `add_wrap.cxx` will look for the C function, or rename `add.c` to `add.cpp` so it compiles as C++.

A typical way to make a C header both C and C++ compatible is:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int add_func(int x, int y);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Another option if you have a C header that you can't change is to wrap its inclusion in `extern "C"` in the .i file so the generated `add_wrap.cxx` will use C linkage for the external functions:

```cpp
%module add
%{
    extern "C" {
        #include "add.h"
    }
%}
%include "add.h"
```